# run remote nodetool commands on Cassandra 3 without authentication

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to run a `nodetool` status command from one **Cass 3** container to another.  I have read that it's possible to do this without authentication but despite following any and all of the suggested steps I've found I have been unable to get it to work.  I either get:
`ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'`
or

```
SecurityException: 'Authentication failed! Credentials required
```

To be clear it does work with a password file so this isn't a connectivity issue.

My understanding is these are the relevant settings:

```
LOCAL_JMX=no  
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

and I have commented these 2 out:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.access"
```

Is anyone able to offer any advice on what I am missing or confirm if they have managed to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the issue wasn't with the config but the fact that I was passing it as params to docker run.  The parameters as listed in the original question didn't seem to override the ones defined in config files within the image consistently.  The answer was to extend the docker file itself with the following:

```
RUN sed -i s/'jmxremote.authenticate=true'/'jmxremote.authenticate=false'/g /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh
RUN sed -i s/'LOCAL_JMX=yes'/'LOCAL_JMX=no'/g /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh
RUN sed -i s/'JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file'/'#JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file'/g /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh
RUN sed -i s/'JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file'/'#JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file'/g /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh
```